# Does R have problems grouping by date?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am new to R and I am having problems with the group_by() function. I read a dataframe and call it df and I want to create a new dataframe with the rows grouped with the ones that have the same exact date (stored in a column named date_pos). However, when I run the code, df_2 is not grouped by date.

If I try to order the dataframe and do arrange(date_pos) the dates are correctly ordered and of course there are varuous rows for the same exact date. Can anyone help me to understand what is going wrong? Thank you in advance

```
library(haven)
library(dplyr)

df <- read_sas("example.sas7bdat")
df_2 <- df %>%
  group_by(date_pos)
```

Comment: you can make operations by date like `df %>% group_by(date_pos) %>% mutate(new_var = fun(old_var))`

Comment: It's hard to understand your problem without sample data - see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. As some of the issue may be how the SAS file is being read in, use something like `dput`  and `head` to capture a sample of the data so others can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0):

From the Examples of the documentation of `group_by`

```
# grouping doesn't change how the data looks (apart from listing
# how it's grouped)
```

Therefore, if you group your data frame it will not change the way it is displayed. However, if you apply any function to the grouped dataframe this will be done within groups. The comment below your answer points this out.

To give you an example:

```
df_2 %>% 
 group_by(date_pos) %>% 
 mutate(grp_mn = mean(some_variable))
```

Will calculate separate means of *some_variable* for each date and add a column to the dataframe with these means.

As you mention to also be able to inspect the grouping visually, you can use `arrange()`